# creating a 9path image

Tags: android-drawable, nine-patch

I tried to create a 9 path drawable for a chat bubble

[image]

I want the image to extend vertically and have the little arrow unchanged.

I followed a few tutorials and added patches to the image then saved it as bubble.9.png but it doesn't work properly in my app. here is a screen shot

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

9-patch drawable needs both horizontal and vertical patches. Your bubble is missing markers on top and bottom lines of image.

Here is quick sample of working 9-patch: 
[image: Sample of how it should like]

More info can be found in official documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/NinePatch.html

You may also try to use official tool for editing 9-patches http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html . It has live preview and it can automatically convert normal image to 9-patch by adding border pixels. You will only need to mark necessary content and stretch areas.

Comment: Specifically, the left and top sides are for scaling, the bottom and right sides define where content (text etc.) will be placed

Comment: I did use draw9patch that ships with android. And after a few tries I got the right scaling in the preview section. The main problem is rendering it in my app. Using setBackgroundResource doesn't work.

Comment: @Amanni I added sample from your 9-patch with all 4 sides containing markers. Also - you can't use 9-patch to only scale in one direction. You will need to use Android layout for correct sizing horizontal stretch.

Comment: Thank you for helping with the patches, do I use this in my java code as I would any other drawable?

Comment: In general - yes. NinePatchDrawable extends drawable so it's expected to behave like drawable. You can look up more info in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/NinePatchDrawable.html